# Shoes 4 - LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/setup

Tags: java, ruby, ubuntu, jruby, shoes

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I'm having some trouble figuring out this issue I'm having with Ruby and [the latest edition of Shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4) straight from Github.

It lists JRuby and JDK as its dependencies - I'm pretty certain I've got JRuby and JDK installed properly (the latter in the form of OpenJDK, both 7 and 8). I've gotten up to the point of successfully (I think) installing Shoes. But when I try to run Shoes on one of its sample apps, I get this error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/setup
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
require at /usr/share/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
(root) at /home/deadman/Apps/shoes4/shoes-swt/bin/shoes-swt:6
load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1059
(root) at /home/deadman/Apps/shoes4/bin/shoes-swt:5
```

I've looked into similar errors that people have encountered, but none of them are for Shoes specifically and I haven't been able to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong here.

Can someone point me in the right direction toward figuring out these errors or recommend a solution? If more information is necessary, I'll post it.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the `bundler` gem installed. Try running `gem install bundler` from the command line.

Comment: @JonCairns - I did actually have `bundler` installed, but tried installing it again anyway. Still no luck.

I also ran `gem server` to make sure, and it lists `bundler 1.11.2` as being installed, as well as the relevant `shoes 4` gems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `warbler` with a non-Shoes app.  I was able to work around the problem by adding the following lines *before* the `require 'bundler/setup'` line:

```
require 'bundler/dep_proxy'
require 'bundler/index'
require 'bundler/match_platform'
require 'bundler/remote_specification'
require 'bundler/stub_specification'
require 'bundler/endpoint_specification'
```

In your case (a Shoes app) there appears to be a few different `require 'bundler/setup'` lines.  Maybe try placing the above at the top of *your* script first, before hacking the gem...